# Send Android inputs without ADB with Termux

Tags: shell, input, adb, termux

Im wondering if there is a way to send inputs like "app switch" or "home" without adb using only termux.
Im trying to make an shortcut to switch apps (like alt+tab) to run on termux, and the way I found is running this code:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH && adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
```

(Run two times to emulate double tap on recent apps button)

It works fine but, everytime I restart Termux app I need to run "adb connect".

I wonder if there is an script or something that can send this inputs to android without the adb.

Comment: You need `root` to send events without `adb`